Terminal: To make Option-Control keyboard shortcut work
I use the fish shell, and I added a function that expands variables like it works by default in Zsh. That is, I can type e.g. $PWD, press the keyboard shortcut, and it will be expanded to the current path.
For some reason though, Option-Control-E doesn't work, whereas Control-E works fine. What might be the reason?
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish:
function fish_user_key_bindings
    # option-control-e, doesn't work
    # bind \e\ce bind_expand_all

    # control-e, works
    bind \ce bind_expand_all
end

~/.config/fish/functions/bind_expand_all.fish:
# $__fish_config_dir/functions/bind_expand_all.fish
function bind_expand_all
    set -l expanded
    for token in (commandline --tokenize)
        set expanded $expanded (eval echo $token)
    end
    set -l new (string join " " $expanded)
    commandline -r $new
    commandline -C (string length $new)
end


As I figured out myself, Control-Option-E works if I open the Termonal's settings, click "Profiles", then "Keyboard", and then enable the "Use Option as Meta key" check box. (There is the same setting for iTerm2.)
But then I have a different question. What is the default Meta key in Terminal.app? Some people say that it is Escape. But Control-Escape-E doesn't expand variables in fish for me. The weird thing is that it does worked once, but I pressed some other keys in a hurry or maybe I pressed some shortcut twice, and didn't noticed what exactly I pressed then.
update: Okay, now I figured it out. To simulate Control-Option-E, you should press Escape first, and then, without releasing it, press Control-Option-E.
